# Extending asp.net identity in asp.net mvc 5 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on asp.net MVC 5 application. I am using Identity for creating users. I am using it first time and creating first mvc 5 application. I have two types of users. I want two tables for both types of users. So first record should be inserted in aspnetuser table and then in related tables and aspnetuser table should be linked with both tables so that i can access them. I have created models for both types of users. How can i link them with identity in model ?

Please suggest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first, you can only truly have one user, at least in terms of the stuff Identity does. You can subclass that single user to create other types, though. So, essentially, you'd have a setup like:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...
}

public class FooUser : ApplicationUser
{
    ...
}

public class BarUser : ApplicationUser
{
    ...
}

public class BazUser : ApplicationUser
{
    ...
}
```

In other words, just one class inherits directly from `IdentityUser`, while all your various types will inherit from that one class (in this case, `ApplicationUser`).

By default, Entity Framework handles inheritance via STI or Single Table Inheritance. How this works is that you'll have just one table `AspNetUsers` (the default table name for the Identity user), and any properties your subclasses add will be added as columns on that table. This means that all your subclass properties have to be nullable, since if a different subclass or just the base `ApplicationUser` class are persisted that property wouldn't be set.

If that's not acceptable, there's other inheritance strategies you can implement, namely TPT (Table-Per-Type) and TPC (Table-Per-Concrete Type). In TPT, the base, shared properties go all in one table and then each subtype has its own table with just columns for the properties it adds. In TPC, every class gets it's own table for everything, so each of your individual subtypes would have all of the Identity columns added. I don't believe this particular option would be compatible with Identity, though, or at the very least it would be highly burdensome as all the foreign key relationships between things like roles and claims would have to be duplicated for each table. Even if you could hack Identity to make that work, you'd lose any cohesive way of doing anything with all users, regardless of type, at once.

Basically, your options are the default, also known as TPH (Table-Per-Hierarchy), or TPT. However, TPT is less efficient because it essentially requires a join for every query just to get the full instance. If you absolutely need to have non-nullable properties on your subclass, it might be an appropriate option. However, remember that the property only needs to be nullable at the database-level. If you go with TPH, you can still require that those properties have values via validation in the application.

Comment: In this scene, is the could you please clarify me if the following approach is true or not? Assume that I have a form (Create) for creating different type of users: FooUser, BarUser, BazUser and there is a **Type** dropdownlist on the Create form in order to determine the user types. In order to make user operations, I should create a ViewModel containing all of three models. During create process, I fill this viewmodel according to the user type and pass it to the Controller. >>>

Comment: >>> Then I will check the user type parameter and create an instance according to the user type (FooUser, BarUser, BazUser). Then fill this new model with the parameters coming from Create page and then pass it to the ASP.NET Identity's  **UserManager.Create()** method. Is this approach fully true? Or is there a better approach for creating a new user with this scenario you mentioned in your answer? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Like I said in a comment on another post, the `UserManager` instance in the scaffolded `AccountController` is an instance of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`. If you use that, all "user" subclasses will be downcast to `ApplicationUser`. You would need an instance of `UserManager<FooUser>`, `UserManager<BarUser>`, etc. to save the right types. Other than that, your approach seems fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Voted+

Comment: There is a problem when retrieving properties of subclasses (FooUser, BarUser, BazUser) bu using ASP.NET Identity UserManager. Could you also post how to reach these custom properties and retrieve data from **AspNetUsers** table? Thanks...

Comment: Again, you need class-specific instances of `UserManager<TUser>`. If you use the `UserManager` property in `AccountController` by default, that is actually an instance of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`. To work with `FooUser`, for example, you need an instace of `UserManager<FooUser>`.

Comment: But when trying to use in that way ı encounter an error like that: *"The type 'FooUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserManager<TUser>'. 
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'FooUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<string>'."* for each case UserManager<ApplicationUser>, UserManager<FooUser> or UserManager<BarUser >. Any idea?

Comment: Does `FooUser` inherit from `ApplicationUser`. If not, it needs to.

Comment: Did you customize the primary key data type? For instance, making it an int instead of the default of string? If so, then you need to instantiate the appropriate version of `UserManager<TUser, TKey>`, rather than just `UserManager<TUser>`.

Comment: Yes, I convert it to int. But I cannot find anything in the entire solution (I searched the entire solution by typing "UserManager<TUser" but there is nothing in the solution. Do I need to add project something extra?

Comment: That's part of Identity, so it's not going to be in your solution. You need to create an instance of `UserManager<FooUser, int>`, i.e. use the generic class signature that takes `TUser` and `TKey` instead of the one that just takes `TUser`.