# How to use subclass of ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my model, I have two classes inherit from ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string SelfIntroduction { get; set; }
}
public class Author : ApplicationUser
{
    public ICollection<Paper> UploadedPapers { get; set; }
}
public class PCMember : ApplicationUser
{
    public int? Quota { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Topic> PreferredTopics { get; set; }
}
```

However, I can't use those two classes in Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "PCMember")]
public ActionResult FinishRegister(string userName, int[] selectedTopics)
{
    var user = UserManager.FindByName(userName);
    string x = ((PCMember)user).UserName;
    // create topics
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedTopics.Count(); i++)
    {
        Topic t = context.Topics.Find(selectedTopics[i]);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(t.TopicName);
    }
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(selectedTopics);
    return View(context.Topics.ToList());
}
```

When I cast user to PCMember (Actually it is), the system will tell me

```
    "Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 
'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser_XXX' to type 
'PaperReviewSystem.Models.PCMember'."
```

That means I use a wrong UserManager or something else?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407251/extending-asp-net-identity-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application

Comment: @barry, the problem is I can't generate instance of ApplicationUser's subclass, not how to store them. I used the TPH for my User model. And if I pass username to the parameter, I can get ApplicationUser but not PCMember, which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (probably, not 100% sure) by making custom UserManager

```
public UserManager<Author> AuthorManager { get; private set; }

public UserManager<PCMember> PCMemberManager { get; private set; }
```

and then I can use it.

```
PCMember user = PCMemberManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result;
```

But, the reason I said it is not 100% sure because in my AspNetUsers table, the discriminator column for the user is "ApplicationUser", I changed it to PCMember, then it works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Alex. How do you instantiate PCMemberManager? Is it using DI?